# jquery, hover over parent, slideToggle child, not work quite well

Tags: javascript, jquery

So when user hover over `div(#cart-quick-view)` `child(.cart_details_box)` needs to slideDown, and to slideUp when mouse gets out of parent(#cart-quick-view). Problem with this code is that sometimes I get 2-3 extra bouncing when mouse is in area of `child(.cart_details_box)`.

**Fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/Y9QLC/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cart-quick-view">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cart_details_box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cart-quick-view {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
 }
 .cart_details_box {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 205px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid #E7E7E7;
    padding: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
    top: 55px;
    right: 0;
 }
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#cart-quick-view').hover(function() { 
        $('.cart_details_box').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the queuing of animations when the mouse enter and leave the parent element quickly. You can use [.stop(true, true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the existing animations to fix it

```
$(function () {
    $('#cart-quick-view').hover(function () {
        $('.cart_details_box').stop(true, true).slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79U6K/)

Comment: I think that using `.stop(true, false)` is more suitable in this case.

Comment: I tried with stop(true, true) and with stop(true, false). It is far better than original code but again it has problems and seems "unnatural".

Comment: what are the problems ?

Answer (score 0):

The `stop()` method is an option, but there is also a jQuery plugin available called [hoverFlow](http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/) that can fix the problem with a better looking transition.